# Laravel: Undefined variable: RoomTypes (View:

Tags: laravel

So i have a simple drop down list that will display the list of data from my database. However im not sure how to display them using my controller. I did something like so:

ShoppingCart.blade.php

```
public function getCheckout(Request $request)
{
    if (!Session::has('cart')) {
        return view('shop.shopping-cart');
    }

    $RoomTypes = Room::all(); // RoomTypes are defined here
    $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $total = $cart->totalPrice;
    $checkIn = $request->input('checkIn');
    $checkOut = $request->input('checkOut');
    $RoomTypes = $request->input('RoomTypes');
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($checkIn);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($checkOut);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    $days = $interval->format('%a'); // now do whatever you like with $days
    $total = $days * $cart->totalPrice;

    $post = Order::where('checkIn', '=', $checkIn)
        ->where('checkOut', '=', $checkOut)
        ->get();

    if (count($post) > 1) {
        return redirect()->route('posts.shopping-cart')->with('Sorry this date has been taken');
    }

    return view('posts.checkout', [
        'total'     => $total,
        'checkIn'   => $checkIn,
        'checkOut'  => $checkOut,
        'RoomTypes' => $RoomTypes,
    ]);
}
```

Then in my view:

```
<select name="RoomType" id="RoomType" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="state">
    <option value="">Room type</option>

    @foreach($RoomTypes as $RoomType)
        <option value="{{$RoomType}}">{{$RoomType}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

If anyone could help me figure out a way of displaying the room types on my page using a function or potentially implementing the method into the getcheckout function that will help.

Comment: What is your problem??

Comment: Yes sorry how could i forget to put the error message in :/ i will update the title of the question

Comment: first check `dd($post);` If goes to `if condition` then you get this error

Comment: unable to do the dd because whenever i go to the page it just comes up with the undefined variable error

Comment: Why do you use `$RoomTypes = Room::all();` and `$RoomTypes = $request->input('RoomTypes');`. Why same variable name used

Comment: Cause im initially trying to retrieve all the RoomTypes from my database. Then the second part is requesting the user input for the drop down menu called Room Types. How would you change this ?

Comment: First `$RoomTypes` is an array and Second `$RoomTypes` is a variable. This is the main problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212015/discussion-between-codingkid-and-a-a-noman).

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like the following:

```
public function getCheckout(Request $request)
{
    if (!Session::has('cart')) {
        return view('shop.shopping-cart');
    }

    $RoomTypes = Room::all();
    $userInputRoomTypes = $request->input('RoomTypes'); // Renamed var to avoid overwriting $RoomTypes

    // ... 

    return view('posts.checkout', [
        'total'              => $total,
        'checkIn'            => $checkIn,
        'checkOut'           => $checkOut,
        'RoomTypes'          => $RoomTypes,
        'userInputRoomTypes' => $userInputRoomTypes,
    ]);
}
```

Finally, this might work inside your HTML. Not really sure what you are trying to achieve by passing the request data back, but if you want to select an option:

```
<select name="RoomType" id="RoomType" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="state">
    <option value="">Room type</option>

    @foreach($RoomTypes as $RoomType)
        <option value="{{$RoomType}}" {{ !old('RoomType', request('RoomType')) === $RoomType ?: 'selected' }}>{{$RoomType}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```